# How to get the value of input type="date" using Ember.js handlebars?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember.js. I have this date input field and i want to fire an action every time the client changes the date. Although you don't need it here is the method handling the action:

```
getDate(){
    console.log("HELLO WORLD!")
}

/* {{input value=model.date class="ux-serviceform-body-name w-input" type="date}} */
```

How could I include an action handler in this field ?

I already tried

```
"on-change='getDate'"}}
"on='change' action='getDate'"}}
"action='getDate'"}}
```

None of the above solutions did the job.

Comment: You have a `"` missing in your hbs file `type="date"`

Comment: If that is not the problem just post a twiddle explaining your problem, because I'm sure it should work as expected with any `type`

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `change=(action "getDate")`. This will give you the event fired.

If you only want to get new value, then use `change=(action "myaction" value='target.value')`.

Here it is:

```
{{input type="date" change=(action "myaction" value='target.value')}}
```

You can look at [this api doc](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_actions).

Comment: I never expected type="date" will provide such wonderful date picker !..Could you please explain where is it UI coming from ? is there any support for date with time ?.

Comment: It is coming from [html5 `input type=date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). Actually, Firefox is not supporting it. You can check the [browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type%3D%22date%22). Using some [html 5 polyfills](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=html5+input+date+polyfill) can help. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support) also provides writing a polyfill. But we generally use [ember-pikaday](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday) in our projects.

Comment: Also you can use `input type="datetime-local"` for date with time. [Resource](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-(type=datetime-local))

Comment: Thank you @ykaragol